# How to create a profile tag system like in facebook?

Tags: android, tags, system

I'm wondering if someone can help me on how to make such system. I'm building an android  social app and I want users to be able to mention other users on their posts like in `facebook` using `@ProfileName`. Do you guys have any idea or material indication on that subject?